# Como fazer um substituição usando a lista tupla , em python

Tags: python, lista, tupla

A questão pede para :

Um restaurante do tipo buffet oferece apenas cinco tipos básicos de
comida. Pense em cinco pratos simples e armazene-os em uma tupla.
• Use um laço for para exibir cada prato oferecido pelo restaurante.
• Tente modificar um dos itens e cerifique-se de que Python rejeita a mudança.
• O restaurante muda seu cardápio, substituindo dois dos itens com pratos
diferentes. Acrescente um bloco de código que reescreva a tupla e, em seguida,
use um laço for para exibir cada um dos itens do cardápio revisado.

````
for comida in buffet : 
    print (comida)```


Mas eu não estou conseguindo fazer a substituição 

eu já tentei ```buffet[0,1] =( "jaca" , "angu" )
                buffet(0,1) =( "jaca" , "angu" )
                buffet = ( "jaca" , "angu" )```

As duas primeiras dão erro , a ultima substituiria toda a lista
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O intento deste exercício é comparar a característica de [`imutabilidade`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_imut%C3%A1vel) dos tipos primitivos [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#lists) e [`tuples`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#tuples) em Python.

Veja só uma possível solução comentada passo-a-passo:

```
# Um restaurante do tipo buffet oferece
# apenas cinco tipos básicos de comida.
# Pense em cinco pratos simples e
# armazene-os em uma tupla.

cardapio = ('arroz','feijao','batata','salada','farofa')

# Use um laço for para exibir cada
# prato oferecido pelo restaurante

for prato in cardapio:
    print(prato)

# Tente modificar um dos itens e cerifique-se
# de que Python rejeita a mudança.

try:
    cardapio[0] = 'pizza'
except TypeError:
    print('Tuplas sao imutaveis!')

# O restaurante muda seu cardápio, substituindo
# dois dos itens com pratos diferentes. Acrescente
# um bloco de código que reescreva a tupla

cardapio = list(cardapio)  # Converte Tupla Para Lista
cardapio[0] = 'jaca'       # Altera o primeiro prato do cardapio
cardapio[1] = 'angu'       # Altera o segundo prato do cardapio
cardapio = tuple(cardapio) # Reescreva a tupla

# Em seguida, use um laço for para exibir cada
# um dos itens do cardápio revisado.

for prato in cardapio:
    print(prato)
```

Saída:

```
arroz
feijao
batata
salada
farofa
Tuplas sao imutaveis!
jaca
angu
batata
salada
farofa
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/RoyalblueEnchantedTriggers)

Comment: Muito Obrigado !!

Answer (score 1):

A tupla tem a premissa de ser imutável, o que significa isso ? Você é capaz de ver o que tem em cada posição da tupla mas não é capaz de muda-lá. Tuplas se assemelham a strings. Sempre que você tenta alterar o conteúdo de uma tupla o interpretador irá acusar um erro, perceba que, você não pode alterar o conteúdo de uma tupla mas pode, com a mesma variável, receber outra tupla.

A estrutura de dados lista é mutável, então você deve converter a tupla para lista, adicionar o conteúdo novo e retornar para tupla.

```
a = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
for i in a:
    print(i)

print()

aux = list(a)
aux[0] = 1
aux[1] = 'biscoito'
a = tuple(aux)

for i in a:
    print(i)
```